# How can I get the first (most significant) N digits in a positive integer, without counting the total number of digits in it?

Tags: arithmetic

I can calculate the number of digits in $x$:

$$M=\Big\lfloor\log_{10}{x}\Big\rfloor+1$$

And then calculate the first $N$ digits in $x$:

$$\Big\lfloor\frac{x}{10^{M-N}}\Big\rfloor$$

Is there any trick to achieve that without counting the number of digits in $x$ to begin with?

Comment: I don't quite understand. How exactly are you "presented" the number? If you're presented it as a stream of digits starting from most significant, it's trivial. If the stream starts from least significant, it's impossible without knowing all the digits. If you're given the entire number, it's trivial to count the number of digits either directly, or through logs, as you've shown. So the problem needs more context.

Comment: Probably, you search the first $N$ digits for a number $n$ that is given with a formula, for example $n=3^{123}$ or $n=3^{100}-2^{123}$ or $n=123!$ ?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  As others have indicated, the form in which you are given the number matters.  If it is a string of digits, then there is no problem.  If it is something else, such as $N=\lfloor \sqrt {\exp (2023)+2023!}\rfloor$  or whatever then you'll probably want to work with the log.

Comment: @lulu: The number is given as a positive integers. I can do any mathematical operation on it (including, of course, calculating its string representation, which I would like to avoid).

Comment: @Lourrran: see my comment above.

Comment: @Deepak: see my comment above.

Comment: I don't understand what it means to be given  numbers as "positive integers".  Can you be more precise?  Exactly *how* is your number given to you?

Comment: @lulu: Not sure how else I can explain this. If you're looking for the programming-language equivalence, then I guess that `int`, `unsigned int`, `uint256`, etc, would be a good analogy.

Answer (score 1):

$x = 12345678$

$y = log_{10}(x)$

$z = \left\lfloor y \right\rfloor$

$t=y-z$

$u= 10^t$

And then work with $u$